# ¿leer una cadena desde un fichero en c#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

estoy ocupando este codigo para leer una linea entera en excel, pero quiero  leer solo una celda o una cadena

```
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:\Users\Public\TestFolder\Base.xls");



        line = file.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

Para acceder a un archivo excel no podras hacerlo con un `StreamReader` ya que este no entendera el formato del archivo, vas a tener que usar alguna libreria, aconsejaria que sean basadas en `open xml` como ser

[ClosedXML - The easy way to OpenXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/)

Para leer una celda usarias

```
 var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
 var ws = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Cell Values");

 string callValue = ws.Cell(2, 2).Value;
```

Por supuesto tambien aconsejaria que uses el excel en formato xlsx o sea en als versiones ams nuevas de excel asi sera compatible con open xml